# How Blazor Wasm load local file?

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly

I am having a question on loading a local file using Blazor Wasm. Below is a simple way to read the file size. But I keep getting the exception "Could not find file." I have been searching and found no result about it except something about browser security.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="clikMe">Click me</button>

@code {
    private void clikMe()
    {
        string file = "file:///C:/Users/user01/Downloads/test.txt";
        long nowFileSize = new FileInfo(this.file).Length;
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you need to use an `input type="file"`. because, for _obvious_ security reasons, browsers _prevent_ code run inside a website from arbitrarily accessing local files.

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
<InputFile OnChange="@((e) => OnChange(e))" />
<button @onclick="ReadFiles">Read File</button>

@code {
     IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile>? files = new List<IBrowserFile>();
     void OnChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
     {
        files = e.GetMultipleFiles();
     }
     async Task ReadFiles()
     {
        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // get the file size
                var buffer = new byte[file.Size];
                // read the text file
                await file.OpenReadStream().ReadAsync(buffer);
                // convert byte array to string
                var content = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
                // print results(content of file) to console
                Console.WriteLine(content);
             }
         }
      }
  }
```